# How many Afghans have migrated/fled to the (present-day territory of the) EU in the past 25 years? And how many were granted asylum?

Tags: european-union, immigration, afghanistan

I'm trying to figure out from a migration perspective how much of an issue this is/was. But I can't get any total figures on a quick google search, unlike say for Syria. This may well be because of the longer time span involved, as well as the expansion/changes of the EU in the same period. So, is there even a ballpark estimate for Afghan migration to present-day territory EU in the past 25 years? (You may include the UK area, if that makes it any easier to come up with an answer.)

N.B. I found some [yearly] numbers [for Greece](https://ec.europa.eu/migrant-integration/index.cfm?action=media.download&uuid=FC2FEB61-A69C-758E-4BBB990D8936BF04), in the 2001-2012 period, which are sourced from FRA, but without citing a particular FRA document... The numbers varied significantly from some 757 in 2011 (min) to 15,314 (in 2008, max). It's pretty hard to extrapolate Europe-wide from these though...

Comment: I don't know if there would be as much detail as you're looking for but I would explore the [UNHCR data](https://www.unhcr.org/refugee-statistics/).

Answer (score 4):

Incomplete but useful.

Between 1998 and 2019 - 265,419

[Taken from this site](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/bookmark/eb87e117-62c3-4b9c-ac72-3cf51f008469?lang=en)

Comment: That graph should be a table.

Comment: The link is to a table.

Comment: That seems to be total immigration without regard to asylum or refugee status.

Answer (score 0):

Again, a partial image, but according to a letter [cited](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2021-08-10/six-countries-urge-eu-not-to-stop-deportations-to-afghanistan-belgium-says) by Reuters:

> Since 2015, around 570,000 Afghans have requested asylum in the EU, the letter from the six EU countries noted, 44,000 in 2020 alone, making Afghanistan the second most important country of origin last year.

(The six countries whose ministers signed that letter were  Germany, Austria, Belgium, Greece, Netherlands and Denmark, FWTW.)